# If $\gcd(|x|,|y|) = 1$ then $|xy| = \mathrm{lcm}(|x|,|y|)$ in an abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, abelian-groups

I am trying to prove this

> If $\gcd(|x|,|y|) = 1$ then $|xy| = \mathrm{lcm}(|x|,|y|)$ in an abelian group.

My idea was we have the following 
$|x||y| = lcm(|x|,|y|)\times gcd(|x|,|y|)$ since we have $gcd(|x|,|y|) = 1$

$|x||y| = lcm(|x|,|y|)$

Suppose that $|x| = n $, $|y| = m$ , and $ |xy| = q$. 
Consider now $(xy)^{nm}$ = $x^{{n}^m}  y^{{m}^n}$ = $e$
Hence we have $q | nm$ I want to go the other direction as well that is $nm | q$ in order to get $q = nm = lcm(|x|,|y|)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $nm$ divides $q$ it suffices to show that $n$ divdes $q$ and $m$ divides $q$ and then apply Gauss' Lemma.

Now $(xy)^q=1$ implies $a:=x^q=y^{-q}$. The order of $x^q$ must divide $n$ (because $(x^q)^n=(x^n)^q=1_G$) and the order of $y^{-q}$ must divide $m$. Hence, the order of $a$ must divide $n$ *and* $m$, that is, the order of $a$ divides $\gcd(n,m)=1$.

Hence, $x^q=1$ and $y^{-q}=1$. This shows that $n$ divides $q$ and $m$ divides $q$ (because $n$ is the order of $x$ and $m$ the order of $y^{-1}$) and we are done.